# Find the number of a feature in categorical data in a Pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, find

I am working on a dataframe like this:

[image]

So I am trying

`number_of_value = df.[df[feature]==value]`

where `feature = 'workclass'` and `value = Private`. But I get an empty dataframe with all columns.

What I need is the output be

`number_of_value = 13`

I know I can define a function to iteratively check for each row, but pandas has it, right?

Comment: `df['workclass'].value_counts()['Private']` will give you the number you want.

Comment: @ALollz I got it! Thanks!